# Azure AD Integrated Authentication

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, windows-authentication, azure-authentication

I want to implement something like the Windows Integrated Authentication, where the user data was read from your pc which was in the intranet of the organisation.

We have registered our organisation on Azure and set up the Azure AD and we have apps that use SSO to connect to the AD and retrieve user data from it. We are also able to login to our devices with "name.surename@organisation.onmicrosoft.com" account.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to automatically authentificate the user to our web apps, just by using the pc login information?
2. Is there a Authentification Scheme that allows us to use the Azure AD to authentificate the user in a way it is done with the Windows Integrated Authentication

The end goal would be to have something like Windows Integrated Authentication but with the device in the Azure Domain of the organisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Is it possible to automatically authentificate the user to our web
> apps, just by using the pc login information?

Yes, It is possible. But you need a lot of work to do. You can [**configure your application for SSO with Azure AD.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps)This need Azure AD premium first.

Then,you need to use [**Azure AD join**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/device-management-introduction) to let your devices in your organization join Azure AD. But this requires all your devices are windows 10.

After joining Azure AD, you can use the Azure AD account to sign in your device and you will found that you can **Single-Sign-On (SSO) to your Azure managed SaaS apps and services**. Your users don’t see additional authentication prompts when accessing work resources. The SSO functionality is even when they are not connected to the domain network available.

> Is there a Authentification Scheme that allows us to use the Azure AD
> to authentificate the user in a way it is done with the Windows
> Integrated Authentication

I understand what you want. Actually,Azure AD doesn't work as local AD and may not have some features as local AD. It doesn't support kerberos neither. As the above I mentioned, you can use Azure AD join to achieve what you want. Join your devices to Azure AD, you can just manage them via Azure AD because they are under your organization.

Comment: So you are saying that the integrated security should work out of the box. But in our case it does not. We just want to avoid the SSO window for our web applications. 

Imagine this scenario: if you login into your windows machine with your outlook account and when you open outlook.com or office360 you should be automaticaly logged in with your outlook account. Do you maybe know if this is possible.

Comment: Hi,@IgorJakovljevic . The SSO is for the applications that integrated Azure AD.If you didn't register outlook app in Azure AD, you cannot use SSO for it.